# Prevent file access from hanging when luks volume is suspended

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

I've got a luks volume setup and mounted, and when not in use I suspend it with `cryptsetup luksSuspend` so it cannot be accessed. But if I forget it's suspended and try to do any kind of file access in the mounted directory, the process just hangs, instead of failing immediately. `CTRl-C` doesn't work to kill it, and `CTRL-Z` doesn't work to put it in the background. Even `sudo kill -9` doesn't help.

Is there a way to make these commands fail fast when the volume is suspended?

If it's relevant, the volume is setup on a loop device backed by a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending all accesses until the passphrase is entered again is the whole point of `luksSuspend`. If you want to ensure that the encrypted device is not in use, call `luksClose`.